# Right constraints not working properly on iphone SE

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, constraints, xib

Im using stack views and constraints in my app. The problem i have encountered is that the view is working properly in iphone 7, but when i turn to iphone SE my text is positioned away from my screen. These are the constraints:
[image]

Comment: show all the constraints of each of the item in your screenshot view

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal i added all the screenshots

Comment: define the leading constraints of the right items in your cell

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal if i only add leading constraints without changing anything else nothing happens, if i remove trailing it works for iphone SE but in iphone 6,7 leaves a blank space in the end.

Comment: its a bit difficult to explain like this. can you please share your code containing only the UI on my email id

Comment: @SamarthKejriwal dont worry man i fixed it. i had forgot to place constraints in my view controller. I had created the file a long time ago and i was thinking that it was table view controller. with the table view constraints works perfect! Thanx for your time :)

Comment: Great :) ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following constraints in the following screenshots :

[image]

Trailing space to Status Label >= 63

Add the right-hand side constraints also for the Status Label.

same do for the "Ordered Date" and "Ordered Time" label